# Is this type-class constraint necessary or redundant?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

The following code successfully compiles, but gets a warning when using GHC 9.2.3 with `-Wredundant-constraints`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Functor f => C f where c :: f Int

instance (Functor f, Applicative f) => C f where c = pure 42
```

The resulting warning:

```
test.hs:5:10: warning: [-Wredundant-constraints]
    • Redundant constraint: Functor f
    • In the instance declaration for ‘C f’
  |
5 | instance (Functor f, Applicative f) => C f where c = pure 42
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, if I remove this constraint, the code no longer type checks:

```
test.hs:5:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (Functor f)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Applicative f
        bound by the instance declaration at test.hs:5:10-29
      Possible fix:
        add (Functor f) to the context of the instance declaration
    • In the instance declaration for ‘C f’
  |
5 | instance Applicative f => C f where c = pure 42
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This confuses me.

Is this constraint truly redundant, or is it in fact necessary?

Intuitively I would say that it is redundant, as it is implied by `Applicative f` already! But GHC begs to differ so I'm unsure.

Comment: Older GHC version actually don't produce the redundant-constraint warning. (But that doesn't really help us... it still seems like it _should_ be redundant.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Indeed! This question is based on warnings that I started getting when giving newer GHCs a spin! And I don't like having warnings, but I also don't like my code not type checking :)

Comment: There's obviously a GHC bug here. Could you file a ticket?

Comment: @dfeuer Ok. So given K. A. Buhr's answer it seems that the bug is in the warning rather than in the resolution/checking (I wasn't sure which one was the bug). I'll file this bug.

Comment: @dfeuer: Done, https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/21765

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the `Functor f` looks redundant, but it is needed to avoid a problem with recursive superclasses leading to a dictionary containing a superclass field that is actually bottom (i.e., an infinite loop at runtime when the superclass is implicitly accessed).

There is an explanation in the compiler source `compiler/GHC/Tc/TyCl/Instance.hs`, in the section titled ["Recursive superclasses"](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/a2f693f524830c2ab1e8a6e9d729839ac8b468c5/compiler/GHC/Tc/TyCl/Instance.hs#L1461).  The upshot is that when resolving the superclass `Functor f` for the `instance C f`, GHC isn't allowed to use `Applicative f` to resolve `Functor f` because `Applicative f` isn't a "smaller dictionary" (see below) than `C f`.  By requiring that superclasses be resolved only through a chain of ever-smaller dictionaries, GHC can ensure that superclass resolution terminates.

In contrast, no `Functor f` is needed in the instance definition for this similar example:

```
class Functor f => C f x
instance (Applicative f) => C f Int
```

because `Applicative f` is a smaller dictionary than `C f Int`, so GHC is allowed to use it.

"Smaller dictionary" here is used in a particular technical sense.  The size of a dictionary is the number of constructors and variables in its type.  So, `Applicative f` is of size 2, while `C f Int` is of size 3.

This means that `Functor f` *isn't* actually redundant and so the warning is wrong.  Issuing the warning looks like a GHC bug.

Comment: Thanks! Following your input I've simplified the example as I now understand it has nothing to do with multi param type classes.

So I understand that class instance contexts require some "redundancy" that other contexts do not, but `-Wredundant-constraints` is apparently unaware of it at the moment, right?